# Python program unexpectidely dies

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, machine-learning, lasagne

I am training an **LSTM network** using *lasagne*, but my program dies without any error during the training. If I use a much smaller dataset ( only 13 data points) the entire code runs.
I was initially using my GPU and thought that the memory was running out. But even though I used CPU It dies.

```
import resource
rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_DATA
resource.setrlimit(rsrc,(1024, resource.RLIM_INFINITY ))
```

My final attempt was to try this but to no avail.